# Archive post by meta value + 24hours

Tags: php, post-meta, meta-query, sql

I'm using this code to archive some custom post type :

```
$where .= " AND wp_postmeta.meta_value >= now()";
```

The metavalue is a date field. On the day of the value of the datefrom has been setup the post gets archive.

I would like it to be stored as archive 1 day after the meta date.

Is there any way to change

```
$where .= " AND wp_postmeta.meta_value >= now()";
```

By +24 hours instead of now? If yes, how is that possible?

Below is the complete function:

```
 function custom_posts_where( $where, $query ) {
    if (is_singular()) return $where;

    if (($query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'events' || (is_array($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'][0] == 'events'))) {
        $year = 0;
        $month = 0;
        if (preg_match('@/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/@', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $refer_match)) {
            $year = $refer_match[1];
            $month = $refer_match[2];

        }
        else if (preg_match('@/([0-9]{4})//@', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $refer_match)) {
            $year = $refer_match[1];
        }

        if (is_archive()) {
            if (!is_month() && !is_year()) {
                $where .= " AND wp_postmeta.meta_value >= now()";
            }
            else {
                $where = preg_replace("@AND.*?\) \)@i", '', $where);
                if (is_month() || is_year()) {
                    $where .= " AND YEAR(wp_postmeta.meta_value) = " . $query->query_vars['year'];
                }
                if (is_month()) {
                    $where .= " AND MONTH(wp_postmeta.meta_value) = " . $query->query_vars['monthnum'];
                }
            }
        }
```

-- EDIT --

Below is the full set of functions to archive the post from the meta value:

```
/* ############################################################################### */
/* ########## START: these are the problem functions ############# */

function custom_posts_orderby( $orderby, $query ) {
    if (is_singular()) return $orderby;

    if (($query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'events' || (is_array($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'][0] == 'events')) && !is_month()) {
        if (is_archive()) {
            if (!isset($query->query_vars['orderby']) || $query->query_vars['orderby'] == '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_1_fieldID_5_numInSet_0') {
                $orderby = "wp_postmeta.meta_value ASC";
            }
        }

        if (stripos($orderby, 'post_title') !== false) {
            $orderbys = explode(" ", $orderby);
            $orderbys[0] = "trim(" . $orderbys[0] . ")";
            $orderby = implode(" ", $orderbys);
        }
    }

    $year = 0;
    $month = 0;
    if (preg_match('@/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/@', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $refer_match)) {
        $year = $refer_match[1];
        $month = $refer_match[2];
    }
    else if (preg_match('@/([0-9]{4})//@', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $refer_match)) {
        $year = $refer_match[1];
    }

    if ($year > 0 || $month > 0) {
        $orderby = "wp_postmeta.meta_value ASC";
    }

    return $orderby;
}

function custom_posts_join( $join ) {
    global $wp_query, $wpdb;
    if (is_singular()) return $join;

    if (($wp_query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'events' || (is_array($wp_query->query_vars['post_type']) && $wp_query->query_vars['post_type'][0] == 'events')) && !is_month() && stripos($join, 'postmeta') === false) {
        if (is_archive()) {
            $join .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id";
        }
    }

    return $join;
}

function custom_parse_query( $query ) {
    if ($query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'events' || (is_array($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'][0] == 'events')) {
        if (is_archive()) {
            $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_1_fieldID_5_numInSet_0';
            $query->query['meta_key'] = '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_1_fieldID_5_numInSet_0';
        }
    }
}

function custom_posts_where( $where, $query ) {
    if (is_singular()) return $where;

    if (($query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'events' || (is_array($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'][0] == 'events'))) {
        $year = 0;
        $month = 0;
        if (preg_match('@/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/@', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $refer_match)) {
            $year = $refer_match[1];
            $month = $refer_match[2];

        }
        else if (preg_match('@/([0-9]{4})//@', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $refer_match)) {
            $year = $refer_match[1];
        }

        if (is_archive()) {
            if (!is_month() && !is_year()) {
                $where .= " AND wp_postmeta.meta_value >= now()";

            }
            else {
                $where = preg_replace("@AND.*?\) \)@i", '', $where);
                if (is_month() || is_year()) {
                    $where .= " AND YEAR(wp_postmeta.meta_value) = " . $query->query_vars['year'];

                }
                if (is_month()) {
                    $where .= " AND MONTH(wp_postmeta.meta_value) = " . $query->query_vars['monthnum'];
                }
            }
        }

        else {
            if (!is_search || is_home() ) {
                $where .= " AND wp_postmeta.meta_value >= now()";
            }
            #} else {
                #$where .= " AND (wp_postmeta.meta_value = '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_1_fieldID_5_numInSet_0' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value >= now())";
                #meta_key   '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_1_fieldID_5_numInSet_0'
                #meta_value '2013-10-28'
            #}
        }
    }
    return $where;
}

function custom_posts_exclude( $query ) {
    # do we need to put some stuff here?
}

# only affect the front-end pages only, not the admin
if ((!is_admin() || ( isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'awpqsf_ajax'))) {
    //if (!$_GET['post_type_index']) {
        add_filter('posts_orderby', 'custom_posts_orderby', 10, 2);
        add_filter('posts_join',    'custom_posts_join');
        add_filter('parse_query',   'custom_parse_query');
        add_filter('posts_where',   'custom_posts_where', 10, 2);
        add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_exclude' );
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a MySQL question and not related to WordPress but you can replace `now()` with `NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: Didn't change anything unfortunately :( :( any other tips ?

Comment: The function I stated is the MySQL function to add 1 day to now()
First of all make sure to also select on the meta key and check how the dates are actually stored, maybe it's not even targatable with a MySQL datetime function

Comment: the date is stored to a meta key: _simple_fields_fieldGroupID_1_fieldID_5_numInSet_0

Via simplefields and gravity form.

Does this hep ??

I don't have any knowledge of SQL unfortunately :( Thanks for your time, really appreciate !

Comment: I've edit the post with the all archive system function in case it helps . .

Comment: Shame on me, I just add to repalce the 1 by -1 !

Thx !!!